# How to configure qemu for mips64 architecture

Tags: qemu

I am working on a project , for that I have to first install qemu. it is mips64 architecture. Can anyone inform me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first go to qemu folder on terminal
then type this
./configure --target-list=mips64-softmmu

then press make

then sudo make install